# Analog of Java's @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection") for Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, spell-checking, suppress-warnings, suppression

Is there any way to mark files, class, variable, *or* something else with something like `@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")` in Java/Kotlin, but on Dart? I'm using Android Studio

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Do you use Dart plugin?

Comment: @onetwo12 I'm using Android Studio. And yes, I have Dart plugin from JetBrains installed